# Using timestamps in a find query with mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I'm trying to run a fairly simple query using MGO that only has one condition included: `published` field must be less than or equal to the current time.

I have a test document in my database that was created as follows:

```
db.articles.insert([{
    "title": "Woo this is a test title",
    "published": ISODate("2017-01-02T12:00:00Z")
}])
```

My querying code is:

```
now := time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339)
articlesCollection.Find(bson.M{"published": bson.M{"$lte": now}}).
     Sort("-published").All(&frontPageArticles.Articles)
```

But I get no records returned.

I'm comfortable with Mongo, but very new to Go (and thus mgo) - I'm sure I'm doing something wrong at a basic level, but am not sure what. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple: don't format your time, just pass a `time.Time` value:

```
now := time.Now()
```

The `mgo` package will encode the time in the appropriate format. In your example you passed the time as a `string` which would only work if the `published` field in MongoDB would also be a `string` in the same format (and not a MongoDB `date`).

Comment: Good god, I don't believe it. Thank you, that's worked. Will accept as soon as the timer's up.